# jquery attr('name') returning undefined

Tags: jquery-ui, menuitem

I'm trying to get the name attribute of a selected ui.item in my jquery menu ui. I need the name attribute of the item that has the 'selected' class added to it, but attr('name') is returning undefined. I need to grab that name attribute when the submit button is clicked.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var selection = ' ';

        $(".menu").menu({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
                selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').attr('name');
            } // closes select function
        }); // closes menu

        $("button").button();
        $("button").click(function () {
            alert(selection)
        }); //closes click()
    });
</script>

<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="academic_artStudies">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <h2>Academic: Art Studies</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="academic_Literature">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <h2>Academic: Literature</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="academic_socialSciences">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <h2>Academic: Social Sciences</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="academic_physicalNaturalSci">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <h2>Academic: Physical/Natural Sciences</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.item` returns the `<li>` you clicked on.  It doesn't have a `name` attribute.  The `<a>` tag, that its child, does.  You need to get the `<a>` tag *first*, before you can get the name.

```
selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').children('a').attr('name');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ntUcW/1/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#event-select), ui.item is the active element (clicked), NOT the li element as you have perhaps assumed. From the ui.item you'll need to do `ui.item.children('a').attr('name')` to get the value you are after.

Comment: `ui.item` *is* the `<li>` element.

Comment: nope, ui.item is a jquery collection of elements. ui.item[0] is the first (and only) <li> element in this case. please do check the docs.

Comment: I know it's a jQuery object, and that it contains one element.  I was commenting on your `ui.item is the active element (clicked), NOT the li element`.  That is *incorrect*.